# Do triggers cause other triggers to execute?

Tags: t-sql, triggers, cascading-deletes

I have a question regarding triggers in TSQL.

Let's say I have 3 tables:

```
Companies
---------
Id

Employees
---------
Id
CompanyId

Tasks
-----
EmployeeId
```

Now I create 2 triggers for the top 2 tables `Companies` and `Employees`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteCompany
    ON [dbo].[Companies]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[Employees]
    WHERE CompanyId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)     
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteEmployee
    ON [dbo].[Employees]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[Tasks]
    WHERE EmployeeId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)        
GO
```

So far so good. Now, if I delete a company, the trigger `DeleteCompany` will be executed and the mapped `Employees` will be removed. My question is, will this cause the trigger `DeleteEmployee` to execute? Because I am trying to basically do this but only the first trigger (DeleteCompany) is executed.

Comment: [Create Nested Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx) (which I found by searching for `sql server recursive triggers` - what searches did you attempt to not find this or similar documentation)

Comment: I neither knew of recursive nor nested triggers so I didn't include those keywords in my searches. I just searched for "triggers not deleting all rows " and "not all triggers executing"

Comment: What do you mean by top level triggers ? I assume you are trying to remove all  his `TASKS`,`Employee Info` from the company when he is not there in company any more..Why is this an isuse for you

Comment: I am trying to achieve a cascading delete effect with my triggers, meaning if I delete a Company, then the DeleteEmployee trigger is executed which deletes all Tasks prior to deleting the actual Employee because I have referential constraints so I can't delete entries which still have references somewhere. In my instance, neither the Employees nor the Tasks are removed, but if I take away the Tasks table and DeleteEmployee trigger and try to delete the Company again, the Employees are deleted. By top-level trigger, I am just referring to the first trigger, sorry for the bad wording.

Comment: Why use triggers instead of the `ON CASCADE DELETE` option in the foreign key constraint? It makes what you want to do explicit to anyone and you avoid errors. Even that though isn't the best idea performance-wise. ORMs will delete from the child item upwards automatically. ADO.NET guidance is to do the same manually.

Comment: Because I have multiple delete paths in my DB schema. I just simplified it in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have found the problem. I was a little confused about what `INSTEAD OF` actually does. It turns out, it completely replaces the DELETE so I had to delete the actual record after I deleted it's references like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteCompany
    ON [dbo].[Companies]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[Employees]
    WHERE CompanyId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)  

    DELETE [dbo].[Companies] WHERE [dbo].[Companies].Id IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)   
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteEmployee
    ON [dbo].[Employees]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[Tasks]
    WHERE EmployeeId IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted) 

    DELETE [dbo].[Employees] WHERE [dbo].[Employees].Id IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)            
GO
```

This does the trick and the desired cascading delete effect is achieved.

This is the post that led me to this realization: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672731/how-to-emulate-a-before-delete-trigger-in-sql-server-2005)